# How to import source code in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, layout, open-source, jdeveloper

I have a large application that was built in JDeveloper IDE. The problem was that the whole application has XY-Layout that has been deprecated now. I want to switch whole application to IntelliJ IDEA. Is there anyway to do this? Is IntelliJ IDEA support XY-layout?